# Дублирует onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Добавил в фрагменте обработку еще одной пнопки в тулбаре, а оно продублировало все что бьло в тулбаре. (Два поиска, и всех пунктов по два).
Код фрагмена :

```
 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                new AsinkContact().execute();
                return true;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_contact, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchQueryListener);
}
```

Comment: А это точно весь код фрагмента? Вы onCreateOptionMenu не трогали?

Comment: Юрий, да трогал. Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: если вы в фрагмент добавили тот же файл меню XML , что и в активити, то получили именно то, что должны были. Дело в том, что меню складываются. То есть вам для фрагмента нужно сделать отдельный файл меню с одной кнопкой, она добавится к меню активити

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Вот только маленькая проблема, в ` onOptionsItemSelected `  нужно поменять местами item. А так как они в разньх xml то не знаю как ето сделать.